# Solve the equation: $\exp(z) = - \exp(2\pi)$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

I'm having a hard time solving the equation:

$$e^{z} = -e^{2\pi}$$

I need to determine the solutions with a positive imaginary part and an absolute value in the interval $[3\pi , 7\pi]$.

Thank you, and sorry for my english.

Ida

Comment: Well, can you find one solution?

Comment: You will need a definition of $\exp(z)$ where $z$ is complex.  If you have a "hard time", start by writing down the relevant definitions.

Comment: $$\exp(x+iy) = e^x(\cos(y) + i\sin(y))$$

Comment: As of now I'm this far: exp(z) = -exp(2Pi) + exp(0*i) = -exp(2Pi) * (cos(0) + i* sin(0)) = -exp(2Pi)*1. But from here I'm not really shure what to do

Comment: Just take the natural logarithm and determine that for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $z=2\pi + i(2n+1)\pi$ are the solutions accounting for the different branches of the complex logarithm.

Answer (score 3):

If $x = \Re(z)$ and $y = \Im(z)$, then $e^z = e^{x + iy} = e^x(\cos(y) + i\sin(y))$.  Equating the real and imaginary parts of the equation $e^z = -e^{2\pi}$ gives:

$$e^x \cos(y) = -e^{2\pi} \tag{1}$$
$$e^x \sin(y) = 0 \tag{2}$$

Since $e^x \ne 0$ for any finite real $x$, we must have $\sin(y) = 0$.  IOW, $y$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$.  So $\cos(y) = \pm 1$.

If $\cos(y) = -1$, then equation (1) becomes $-e^x = -e^{2\pi}$, which clearly has the solution $x = 2\pi$.  OTOH, if $\cos(y) = +1$, then equation (1) becomes $e^x = -e^{2\pi}$, which has no real solutions.

So it must be the case that $\cos(y) = -1$, i.e., $y$ is an *odd* multiple of $\pi$.  And then $x = 2\pi$.  Thus,

$$z = 2\pi + i\pi(2n + 1), n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Now, figure out which values of $n$ satisfy your constraints of $\Im(z) > 0$ and $3\pi \le |z| \le 7\pi$.

> $n \in \{1, 2\}$, so $z \in \{ 2\pi + 3\pi i, 2\pi + 5\pi i\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! One question: what do you mean with: "y is an 'odd' multiple of pi"?

Comment: @IdaNielsen: I mean that it's $\pi$ times an odd integer, in order to satisfy the requirement that $\cos(y) = -1$.  IOW, it's $y = \arccos(-1) = \pi$ plus an arbitrary multiple of $2\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** If we write $z = x + iy$ for $x, y$ real, taking the norms of both sizes yields $$\exp x = \exp(2 \pi) .$$ Can you continue from here?

Comment: That minus sign looks wrong.

Comment: As of now I'm this far: exp(z) = -exp(2Pi) + exp(0*i) = -exp(2Pi) * (cos(0) + i* sin(0)) = -exp(2Pi)*1. But from here I'm not really shure what to do

Comment: Once we know that $x = 2\pi$, the equation becomes $\exp (2 \pi + iy) = -\exp(2 \pi)$, and canceling leaves $\exp(i y) = -1$. Can you solve the latter equation?

Comment: Thanks, @J.G.---I misread the original equation and have fixed my answer. Fortunately my hint still applies, mutatis mutandis.